# How Do I Allow PHP File Access to Forbidden Files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to protect files from being downloaded if the link is known. I have a file in my root folder and created a .htaccess file with the following:

```
<Files ~ "\.xlsx$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

When the link (www.domain.com/excel.xlsx) is loaded, the browser produces a 403 Forbidden error. This is correct.

I have placed this PHP file inside a folder within the root:

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="../Excel.xlsx" download>Click to download</a>';
?>
```

But when I click to download, I am given a 403 error again.

How can I allow PHP to access this file and download it with the following code? Thank you!

Comment: You would probably need to create a download proxy file, like `download.php?file=thefilename.xlsx`. In that file you then read the file content with PHP and return it to the browser. Then you can also check things like if the user is logged in etc. or add some CSRF-token to the URL to validate that the request comes from your site. (just search for "force download php " and you will get many examples).

Comment: You use a "routing script". Create a link like `router.php?file=Excel.xlsx` which allows you to use php session information to decide if you want to hand out the file content or not. You also need to send the correct headers in that case. 

Better even is to create a reference like `route/Excel.xlsx` and use http server internal rewriting to re-route such incoming requests to your `route.php` routing script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the moment you are not using php to send the file to the user. The user just clicks a link a tries to access the file directly. So that will end in a `403`.

You have to read the file server-side via php and send it as stream to the user. Here is a code-example:

```
// open the file in a binary mode
$name = './Excel.xlsx';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

// dump the xlsx and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the permission of your .htaccess file, 644 resolved by issue.